# Journalist seeking experts for story on Claude Shannon

Tags: discussion

Pete Barlas, a reporter for [Investor's Business Daily](http://investors.com/default.aspx), is doing a story on [Claude Shannon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claude_Shannon) and needs some help. Are you familiar with his life and work, and would you be willing to help out on such a story?

Comment: This really isn't the right place to ask; there are a number of people still alive who knew Claude Shannon reasonably well, and I suspect you would be better off interviewing some of them.

Comment: Am not sure that this *isn't* the right place to ask. Why not here, after all ?

Comment: @Suresh: Why not? The people who actually knew Claude Shannon are probably not reading this site. It just seems awfully lazy to find people to interview by asking a question here rather than doing the legwork (or phonework, rather) to track down the people who really know about Shannon's life.

Comment: I agree with you re: Shannon's life, but about his work there are probably people here who could speak to it.

Comment: Robert Gallager gave a talk in our institute a couple of years ago in which he shared many interesting anecdotes about Claude Shannon. He mentioned that Shannon had a great influence on him when they were together in Bell labs.

Comment: Gallager would be a great choice for somebody to interview. I also recommend Neil Sloane; he was a coeditor of *Shannon's Collected Papers*.

Comment: Also, Robert Fano

Comment: @Kaveh: I cannot see why this half-off-topic and already finished question should be linked from many pages on the main site.  If there is no reason, please remove the [featured] tag.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi, done. (I added the tag to make it show up in the list on the main site so people familiar with Shanon will see it since as you know meta traffic is not that high.)

Comment: @Kaveh: Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably familiar with his work, but not his life. I'll defer to any information-theorists though.